# Python name visibility

Tags: python, wxpython

I am reading some wxPython code to learn some Python. Bear in mind that I am really a beginner so my question will be obvious to you but to me, it's mystifying, and it will probably teach me a lot to fully understand the question.

Here the code:

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    TITLE = "Frame"
    POSITION = wx.DefaultPosition
    SIZE = wx.DefaultSize
    STYLE = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
    LAYOUT_MANAGER = wx.GridBagSizer()

    def __init__(
            self,
            parent = None,
            id = wx.ID_ANY,
            title = TITLE,
            pos = POSITION,
            size = SIZE,
            style = STYLE,
            name = wx.FrameNameStr
            ):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title, pos, size, style,
                                        name)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.LAYOUT_MANAGER)
        self.panel = MainPanel(parent=self)
```

My question is simply: why do I get `NameError: global name 'LAYOUT_MANAGER' is not defined` if I refer to LAYOUT_MANAGER as follows:

```
self.SetSizerAndFit(LAYOUT_MANAGER)
```

removing the `self` reference, that is.

Why am I confused? Simply because in this method, a reference is made to fields like `POSITION`, `SIZE`, etc without any prefixed `self`, yet the reference is needed if I use the field LAYOUT_MANAGER as an argument to the method `SetSizerAndFit`...

What gives?!

I am probably oblivious of the most natural scoping/visibility rules of the language here.. but given the little I know, it does not make sense to be able to write `size = SIZE` (with no `self.`) but not be able to write just `LAYOUT_MANAGER`, and require `self.LAYOUT_MANAGER`?!

Comment: If you are a beginner wxPython is probably not a good place to start. They use lots of advanced features :). There are many good tutorials for P

Comment: James, does it make sense to you that `pos = POSITION` _sees_ the field `POSITION` without the need to specify it as `self.POSITION` but that capability disappears in the method body? Do you think this peculiarity is unique to wxPython?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say:

> Simply because in this method, a reference is made to fields like POSITION, SIZE, etc without any prefixed self, yet the reference is needed if I use the field LAYOUT_MANAGER as an argument to the method SetSizerAndFit...

Technically, no.  The references to POSITION, SIZE, etc. are not made *inside* the method, they are made in the `def` line.  The `def` line itself has access to the enclosing scope, so it can see the variables `POSITION` and `SIZE` because they exist in that enclosing scope (which is the class body).  However, the actual body of the method does not have access to this scope, so you need to use self.

This difference in scope parallels the difference in when the two are executed.  The `def` statement defines the function, and is executed right when it happens in the source file.  The body of the `def` is not executed until you actually call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments are evaluated at declaration-time, in their enclosing scope, whereas the methos itself is evaluated in a different scope.